# For Python socket, is there a way to set the local interface used?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm using Python socket on a Windows laptop with WiFi and wired ethernet. The wifi is connected to the internet and the wired ethernet is connected to a local network with no internet connection. I would like the socket to send data to a device on the wired network. How do I force the socket to use the wired network interface? The socket can only send data to the device when WiFi is shut off, so I'm assuming it tries to use the WiFi interface when it is available.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind a socket to a specific interface before connecting:

```
s = socket.socket()
s.bind((local_interface_address, 0))
s.connect((remote_addr, remote_port))
```

Or you can use the source address parameter of the `create_connection` method:

```
s = socket.socket()
s.create_connection((remote_addr, remote_port),
                    source_address=(local_interface_address, 0))
```

Comment: I tried both methods and it killed the wired connection with wifi on and off.